# "Bad" effect on appear and disappear of a page element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, rjs

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and the *RJS* template (with Prototype) and I am trying to check if a HTML like the following

```
<div id="test_div_id">...</div>
```

has a attribute of `style="display: none`. If so, in order to display that, I run

```
page.visual_effect(:appear, "test_div_id", :duration => 0.5)
```

What I would like to have, is that, after the div is displayed, the above `page.visual_effect` must not run anymore otherwise I will have a "bad" effect on the front-end caused by the appearance and disappearance of the `div`.

---

The following code seams to work

```
page.visual_effect(:appear, "test_div_id", :duration => 0.5) if page.show "test_div_id"
```

but I don't know if it is a good approach...

Comment: How are you running the effect?

Comment: @ShaneC - Yes. My problem happens on the second (or more) time I run the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really the best description of your problem but the usual thing to do would be to detect a identifier, say 'my_hidden_div_id', and remove the identifier as a callback of the effect applied to it.

Comment: Can you write a simple code example on how to remove the identifier using RJS?

Comment: Not really a fan of rjs to be honest but from what I remember: page['old_identifier'].className = 'new_identifier'

Answer (score 0):

If you've got your effect setup via jQuery you can apply one() to it so that it will only run once.

More details on how you're linking things up would be helpful though.